# SQL Server T-SQL Parser in .NET to check syntax and object existence

Tags: sql, .net, parsing, sql-server-2012

Morning all
Riddle me this. Trying to find a way to parse sql scripts stored in a text field in a database. 
These sql statements are to determine system health and also perform intricate data manipulation at certain times during the month or after certain events. The statements can contain anything from simple select statements to large CRUDs containing recursion, sp calls, variables, temp tables, etc.

I have now cobbled together a solution that sort of does what I need
I can parse the sql for syntax validity, check.
I can check the sql if columns referenced exists. check.
I can report back to the user any error that exists at "design time" i.e. syntactically

The problem is that it is not picking up if a table referenced does not exist. There are a bunch of cases that the parser will only pick up at "run time" when sql is executed.

My proposed solution would be (and this is where I need the communities feedback)
1. Create a .net SQL Connection, transaction and command object
2. Hook the Tx onto the connection and command
3. Execute the SQL in the command and address errors that come up.
4. Irrespective always roll back the Tx

DISCLAIMER: Please do not go on about best practice, I know it isn't, but need to provide usable feedback to the GUI and as far as I can determine, this is the only way to achieve the requirement.

I already use NOEXEC, PARSEONLY and Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom, but again that is only for syntax not actual validity.

Your thoughts and feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: My question is, what would the possible implications be to execute statements as describes in a transaction and then roll it back

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of errors that you don't get via `NOEXEC`?

Comment: re rollback: not everything can be rolled back - extended stored procedure - `xp_cmdshell` for example.

Comment: SET NOEXEC ON;  
SELECT * FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = 'MasterCurrencyConversions';    

SELECT * FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLE] WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = 'MasterCurrencyConversion';    

SELECT * FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = 'MasterCurrencyConversions';    
SET NOEXEC OFF;

Comment: Well, there's always `SET FMTONLY ON` - but that is kinda deprecated; annoyingly, the replacements only process as far as the first grid, and don't work with your example. The advantage of `FMTONLY` over using a transaction is that it has no IO costs and no blocking - but it still could suffer from things like extended stored procedures (you cannot roll back an `xp_cmdshell`)

Comment: If you change one of the .TABLE_NAME to .TABLE_NAMES the error is there as expected, but the error does not come up for .TABLE instead of .TABLES

Comment: Yes; if the *table* isn't found, and it isn't executing, it defers judgement on whether it is valid (this makes it easy to create scripts without having to worry about the order); however, if a *column* isn't found, it is more eager to criticize.

Comment: So the solution would be to use NOEXEC and FMTONLY in 2 seperate calls (repeatedly) until all errors has been resolved? What is meant with "process as far as the first grid"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, what would the possible implications be to execute statements as describes in a transaction and then roll it back

The main issue there is that not everything can *be* rolled back. If the scripts are using things like `xp_cmdshell`, expect pain. But that kinda goes with the territory.

A better alternative to a *transaction* is: `FMTONLY`. This is *kinda similar*, but rather than do work and then undo it, it simply short-circuits everything that would involve rows. This means that it has no IO cost, no rollback cost, and won't cause blocking. It does, however, suffer from the same issues re things like `xp_cmdshell`. Additionally, note that MSDN has the caveat:

> Do not use this feature. This feature has been replaced by sp_describe_first_result_set (Transact-SQL), sp_describe_undeclared_parameters (Transact-SQL), sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (Transact-SQL), and sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object (Transact-SQL).

Unfortunately, as the names suggest: these only work for the **first** result set. If we take your `[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLE]` example from the comments, and try that with SQL-Server's suggested option:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'
SELECT * FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = ''MasterCurrencyConversions'';
SELECT * FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLE] WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = ''MasterCurrencyConversion'';
SELECT * FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = ''MasterCurrencyConversions'';
';
```

then it *works*, returning:

```
is_hidden column_ordinal name            
--------- -------------- ----------------(snipped)
0         1              TABLE_CATALOG   
0         2              TABLE_SCHEMA    
0         3              TABLE_NAME      
0         4              TABLE_TYPE
```

etc - it does not tell us about the problem in the second `SELECT`, because it stopped at the first. Conversely, using the now-deprecated `FMTONLY` option:

```
SET FMTONLY ON;
SELECT * FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = 'MasterCurrencyConversions';
SELECT * FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLE] WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = 'MasterCurrencyConversion';
SELECT * FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = 'MasterCurrencyConversions';
SET FMTONLY OFF;
```

Gives us:

```
TABLE_CATALOG                                          
---------------------------------------------(snipped)

(0 row(s) affected)

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid object name 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE'.
```

So we get our error, but we're using an officially "do not use" feature :(

Additionally, note that it doesn't execute DDL commands; this means that *otherwise valid* operations can fail - for example, here `@Foo` is fine but `#Bar` fails:

```
SET FMTONLY ON;
DECLARE @Foo TABLE (id int not null identity(1,1))
SELECT * FROM @Foo
CREATE TABLE #Bar (id int not null identity(1,1))
SELECT * FROM #Bar
SET FMTONLY OFF;
```

which outputs:

```
id
-----------

(0 row(s) affected)

Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 11
Invalid object name '#Bar'.
```

Comment: Good to know, thank you for the exhaustive examples and thorough explanation